# Install Ruby 2.1.3-p242 with DevKit on target server using chef

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I have two issues that both need to be solved

We use chocolaty to install packages on the windows server, but the version that's on the chocolaty package gallery is version 2.0 and I need a different, more up to date version.  SO, how do I install ruby 2.1.3-p242 and DevKit and run all those DevKit steps?

I have a vague idea on how to do this but I want to hear it from more experienced people in case i miss soothing.

Secondly,
I've been using the embedded ruby that comes with chef on the server, this is because when I tried to install ruby separately, chef installed all the gems to it's embedded version (despite using `gem_package`) but tried to run it using the installed ruby (which yah know, obviously didn't work).

The reason I'm now trying to use a more up-to-date version of ruby is a bit of a long story. 
To cut it short, I'm now using Thor (instead of rake) and Thor didn't work until I installed version 2.1.3 of ruby which is why I need an upgrade.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't something you can really do. The whole point of ChefDK is that it ships its own Ruby, and that includes a lot of C-extension gems compiled against that Ruby. On the plus side, ChefDK already includes Ruby 2.1.3 so you should be all set. Just install the ChefDK package, run `chef gem install thor`, and you should be all set.

Comment: Ok, but what of the second problem?

Comment: If you want to use a different Ruby with gem_package, pass it the path to the correct gem script/executable using the gem_binary parameter.

Comment: ChefDK doesn't include ruby 2.1.3, just ruby-parse, ruby-rewrite and rubocop.

Comment: That is incorrect, it bundles its own Ruby internally, it just doesn't add it to your path.

Comment: I'm looking in the directory on the server, ruby.exe isn't in it. The only ruby is the embedded ruby and thats 1.9 which isn't useful to me.

Comment: Oh sorry, Windows is a different beast. They redist some of the official packages I think.